# how to keep record of activities history in computer

Tags: recording, history

As I live away from my home, my home computer is used by my youngers. I regularly access and check the PC via teamviewer, But they always delete what they browsed and explored.

From now on, I would like to check and keep the complete history for that computer. I can access that computer via teamviewer anytime.

Are there any software (hidden) that can keep records for the activities?

Comment: better asked on super user and you don't mention the operating system...

Comment: You are looking for a technical fix to a social problem? If they delete the browsing history, get an adult to remove their computers for a week! If they engage in cyber-warfare with their parents, confiscate their ipods and make them wear dorky clothes.

Comment: Why the hell are you spying on your relatives?! They obviously don't want you to invade their privacy if they delete histories.

Comment: it's my duty to prevent my own siblings from accessing un-wanted and illegal pages and activities (either online or offline). Unfortunately some of their ill-minded friends misguiding them. That's why I decided to follow and spy on their activities.......please provide some fruitful tips.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the open source keylogger program: [KidLogger](http://www.rohos.com/kid-logger/)

It can log all Web sites visited, chatroom converastions, started programs, opened documents, viewed pictures and movies.

You can find more information in this SuperUser.com answer:
[Is there any program which will keep a 'log' of what I do on my computer?](https://superuser.com/a/85485/144147)

Answer (score 0):

You can download any simple or complex keylogger. A Keylogger can perform different types of functions which range from taking screenshots through to recording all keystrokes on the computer. Some can store these files/images in a secret private folder opened by a unique combination of keys. Some key loggers send a timely report to your email/ftp.

Comment: Do you know of any keyloggers that can be used for this purpose?

Comment: @Anderson Green, see my answer below, and the linked post about KidLogger

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, there is something called the [Zeitgeist Project](http://zeitgeist-project.com/) that is intended to record the user's activities (so that they can search through recent files.) Perhaps it will be useful for Linux users who are trying to record desktop activities.